# Open the Dashboard while remaining on the Same Session

Tags: android, session, authentication, sharedpreferences, back-button

I am able to login to the System, and Logout from the System.When i presses back from the Dashboard without making Logout from the System.I have login to the System eachtime.How can i restrict to loginPage without making the Logout from the System.I need to open the Dashbord page,if the user havenot logout from the System and direct to the Login if the accesstoken time expires

**Login**

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    EditText userName, Password;
    Button login;
    public static final String LOGIN_URL = "http://192.168.100.5:84/Token";
    public static final String KEY_USERNAME = "UserName";
    public static final String KEY_PASSWORD = "Password";
    String username, password;
    String accesstoken, tokentype, expiresin, masterid, name, access, issue, expires, masterid1;

    SessionManagement sessionManagement;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
        userName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_name);
        Password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.login_password);
        userName.setHint(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#008b8b' style='italic'>Username</font>"));
        Password.setHint(Html.fromHtml("<font color='#008b8b'>Password</font>"));
        login = (Button) findViewById(R.id.login);
        login.setOnClickListener(this);

   /*     sessionManagement = (SessionManagement) getSharedPreferences("mySharedPref", 0);
        if (sessionManagement.isLoggedIn()) {

            startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Home.class));

        }    */

    }


    private void UserLogin() {

        username = userName.getText().toString().trim();
        password = Password.getText().toString().trim();
        StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, LOGIN_URL,
                new Response.Listener<String>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(String response) {
                        try {
                            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                            accesstoken = jsonObject.getString("access_token");
                            tokentype = jsonObject.getString("token_type");
                            expiresin = jsonObject.getString("expires_in");
                            username = jsonObject.getString("userName");
                            masterid = jsonObject.getString("MasterID");
                            masterid = masterid.replaceAll("[^\\.0123456789]", "");

                            masterid1 = jsonObject.getString("MasterID");

                            name = jsonObject.getString("Name");
                            access = jsonObject.getString("Access");
                            issue = jsonObject.getString(".issued");
                            expires = jsonObject.getString(".expires");
                            SessionManagement session = new SessionManagement(Login.this);
                            session.createLoginSession(accesstoken, tokentype, expiresin, username, masterid, name, access, issue, expires);
                            // session.createLoginSession(masterid1);
                            openProfile();

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Fetch failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }

                    }
                },
                new Response.ErrorListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                        // Toast.makeText(Login.this, error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Please enter valid username and Password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }) {


            @Override
            public Map<String, String> getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                //params.put("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8");
                return params;
            }

            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put(KEY_USERNAME, username);
                map.put(KEY_PASSWORD, password);
                //map.put("access_token", accesstoken);
                map.put("grant_type", "password");
                return map;
            }
        };
        stringRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                60000, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));


        RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
    }


    private void openProfile() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Home.class);
        intent.putExtra(KEY_USERNAME, username);
        startActivity(intent);
        startActivity(intent);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        UserLogin();
    }


}
```

**SessionManagement**is used for storing access token and other required information

```
public class SessionManagement {

    SharedPreferences pref;
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
    Context _context;
    // Shared pref mode
    int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;
    // Sharedpref file name
    private static final String PREF_NAME = "AndroidHivePref";
    private static final String IS_LOGIN = "IsLoggedIn";
    public static final String KEY_access_token = "access_token";
    public static final String KEY_token_type = "token_type";
    public static final String Key_EXPIRES_IN = "expires_in";
    public static final String KEY_USERNAME = "userName";
    public static final String KEY_MASTER_ID = "MasterID";
    public static final String KEY_MASTER_ID1 = "MasterID";

    public static final String KEY_Name = "Name";
    public static final String KEY_Access = "Access";
    public static final String KEY_Issued = ".issued";
    public static final String KEY_expires = ".expires";


    // Constructor
    public SessionManagement(Context context) {
        this._context = context;
        pref = _context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
        editor = pref.edit();
    }

    SettingFragment context;


    public void createLoginSession(String accesstoken, String tokentype, String expiresin, String username, String masterId, String name, String access, String issued, String expires) {

        editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGIN, true);
        editor.putString(KEY_access_token, accesstoken);
        editor.putString(KEY_token_type, tokentype);
        editor.putString(Key_EXPIRES_IN, expiresin);
        editor.putString(KEY_USERNAME, username);
        editor.putString(KEY_MASTER_ID, masterId);
        editor.putString(KEY_MASTER_ID1, masterId);
        editor.putString(KEY_Name, name);
        editor.putString(KEY_Access, access);
        editor.putString(KEY_Issued, issued);
        editor.putString(KEY_expires, expires);
        editor.apply();

        String user_new_access_token = pref.getString(KEY_access_token, null);
        String user_new_access_tokentype = pref.getString(KEY_token_type, null);
        String user_name_expiresin = pref.getString(Key_EXPIRES_IN, null);
        String user_name_Username = pref.getString(KEY_USERNAME, null);
        String user_name_masterID = pref.getString(KEY_MASTER_ID, null);
        String user_name_name = pref.getString(KEY_Name, null);
        String user_name_access = pref.getString(KEY_Access, null);
        String user_name_issued = pref.getString(KEY_Issued, null);
        String user_name_expires = pref.getString(KEY_expires, null);
        String user_name_masterID1 = pref.getString(KEY_MASTER_ID1, null);


        Log.d("TAG", "Access Token :" + accesstoken + user_new_access_token);
        Log.d("TAG", "TokenType:" + user_new_access_tokentype);
        Log.d("TAG", "Expires in:" + user_name_expiresin);
        Log.d("TAG", "UserName:" + user_name_Username);
        Log.d("TAG", "MasterID:" + user_name_masterID);

        Log.d("TAG", "Name:" + user_name_name);
        Log.d("TAG", "Access:" + user_name_access);
        Log.d("TAG", "Issued:" + user_name_issued);
        Log.d("TAG", "Expires:" + user_name_expires);

        Log.d("TAG", "user_name_masterID1:" + user_name_masterID1);

        //  String user_name_new = pref.getString(KEY_access_token, null);

        //  Log.d("TAG", " :" + accesstoken + " user_name_new:" + user_name_new);


        //  Log.d(tokentype, "admin");
        //ad Log.d(expiresin, "expiresin");

        editor.commit();


    }


    /**
     * Check login method wil check user login status
     * If false it will redirect user to login page
     * Else won't do anything
     */
    public void checkLogin() {
        // Check login status
        if (!this.isLoggedIn()) {
            // user is not logged in redirect him to Login Activity
            Intent i = new Intent(_context, Login.class);
            // Closing all the Activities
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            // Add new Flag to start new Activity
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            // Staring Login Activity
            _context.startActivity(i);
        }

    }


    /**
     * Get stored session data
     */
    public HashMap<String, String> getUserDetails() {
        HashMap<String, String> user = new HashMap<String, String>();
        // user name
        //  user.put(KEY_USERNAME, pref.getString(KEY_USERNAME, null));
        user.put(KEY_access_token, pref.getString(KEY_access_token, null));
        user.put(KEY_token_type, pref.getString(KEY_token_type, null));
        //  user.put(KEY_TOKEN_TYPE, pref.getString(KEY_TOKEN_TYPE, null));
        // user.put(KEY_MASTER_ID, pref.getString(KEY_MASTER_ID, null));
        // user.put(KEY_access_token, pref.getString(KEY_access_token, null));
        // user.put(KEY_NAME, pref.getString(KEY_NAME, null));
        //user.put(KEY_Access, pref.getString(KEY_Access, null));


        // return user
        return user;
    }

    /**
     * Clear session details
     */
    public void logoutUser() {

        editor.clear();
        editor.commit();

        // After logout redirect user to Loing Activity
        Intent i = new Intent(_context, Login.class);
        // Closing all the Activities
        i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

        // Add new Flag to start new Activity
        i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

        // Staring Login Activity
        _context.startActivity(i);
    }


    public String getMasterId() {
        String masterID = pref.getString(KEY_MASTER_ID, null);
        return masterID;
    }


    public String getMasterId1() {
        String masterID = pref.getString(KEY_MASTER_ID1, null);
        return masterID;
    }

    public String getAccess() {
        String accessID = pref.getString(KEY_Access, null);
        return accessID;
    }

    public String getKeyName() {
        String KeyName = pref.getString(KEY_Name, null);
        return KeyName;
    }


    public String getAccesstToken() {
        String user_new_access_token = pref.getString(KEY_access_token, null);
        return user_new_access_token;
    }


    public void clear() {
        Log.d("TAg", "Full Cleared");
        editor.clear();

        // editor.remove(KEY_MASTER_ID);
        // editor.remove(KEY_USERNAME);
        editor.commit();


    }


    /**
     * Quick check for login
     **/
    // Get Login State
    public boolean isLoggedIn() {
        return pref.getBoolean(IS_LOGIN, false);
    }


}
```

> How can i direct to dashboard page if the user has not logout to the
>   system?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have checked the session on the Login page .If **isLoggedIn() == true** then i have switched to the Dashboard page.

**sessionmanagement**

```
  public boolean isLoggedIn() {
        System.out.println("Pref" + pref.getBoolean(IS_LOGIN, false));
        return pref.getBoolean(IS_LOGIN, false);
    }

 public boolean checkLogin() {
        // Check login status


        if (!this.isLoggedIn()) {
            // user is not logged in redirect him to Login Activity
            Intent i = new Intent(_context, Login.class);
            // Closing all the Activities
            i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

            // Add new Flag to start new Activity
            i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);

            // Staring Login Activity



            _context.startActivity(i);

        }

       // return false;
        return false;
    }
```

**Login**

```
if (session.isLoggedIn() == true) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, Home.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
```

> one can do with checking the session expiry time also